# Pipe bash reproduction in c

Tags: c, bash, pipe, execve

I work on a Bash reproduction in C for my school. I try to schematize how I will code the pipe | feature and I wanted your advices. I know that there is a lot of solutions for this on the Web but i don't want the code but the way to do that I want.
I launched good old paint to show you my vision :

[image: Beautifull sketch]

I tried to code a demonstration to prove the concept but it is a fail.
I thought that creating just one pipe for all execves is a very simple solution but i don't know if it could work.

What i'm asking is a more experienced vision to tell me if it could work or not.

Thank you for reading me,

Comment: Maybe you could spawn various processes and communicate them with sockets? I think it is possible, but I doubt it will be easy... Good luck!